# Mule JMS Endpoint with square brackets in topic name

Tags: jms, expression, mule, endpoint

I need a shared durable subscription for a sonic topic in Mule.
For this scenario, topic name should be something like [[test]]testtopic. but Mule doesn't let me enter '[' or ']'.

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="sonicSub" topic="[[test]]testtopic" />
```

I was trying use ASCII characters which doesn't work either. Is there a way to make it work?

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="sonicSub" topic="#['\133']['\133']test#['\135']#['\135']testtopic" />
```

I tried with hex values as well. It doesn't evaluate the hex values.

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="sonicSub" topic="%5b%5btest%5d%5dtesttopic" />
```

Can't I have MEL in endpoints?

Comment: FYI `[[test]]` is not MEL.

Comment: Yes... I wanted to know whether there is a way to give my topic name like [[test]].testtopic

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are illegal characters in Mule URIs and the JMS transport in Mule does not decode encoded characters when it resolves the topic name from the endpoint URI. So, you can not set a topic name with square brackets in the topic attribute (nor the address attribute).

Comment: Agreed. Better use dots as separators, like `test.testtopic` instead of `[[test]]testtopic`.

Comment: Does that mean, I cannot make a shared durable subscription for sonic topic from Mule using the JMS endpoint? Please check the sonic guidelines (page 301) in following link if you have a moment.   http://j2ee-wg.web.cern.ch/j2ee-wg/SonicMQ50/sonicmq_docs/program.pdf

Comment: You might achieve this by creating a custom connector that extends the default JMSConnector by using a custom JMSSupport implementation, or maybe a custom JNDI implementation used by the jms connector. Basically you would just need to fix the issue with parsing the topic name in your implementation. I have never used SonicMQ, though. See the GithHub for Mule JMS if you really need this feature: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/mule-3.4.2/transports/jms